# Excel, Highlight a series of consecutive duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a server availability script that reports 0 or 1 in a .csv file.  I am trying to create a VBA User-defined function in Excel 2010 to analyze each column (server) in the file and highlight all instances in which '1' occurs 3+ consecutive times.

```
Time        srv1  srv2  srv3  srv4
2:01:00 AM     0     0     0     0    
2:21:00 AM     1     0     0     0    
2:41:00 AM     1     0     0     0    
3:01:00 AM     1     0     0     0    
3:21:00 AM     1     0     0     0    
3:41:00 AM     0     0     0     0    
4:01:00 AM     0     0     0     0
```

I'm a total newbie to VBA & UDF's, but here is what I've tried (w/o success):

```
Function HighlightConsecutive(ByRef rng As Range, myNum) As Long
Dim a, i As Long
a = rng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 2) - 1
    If (a(1, i + 1) = myNum) * (a(1, i) = myNum) Then
        CountConsecutive = CountConsecutive + 1
    End If
    If (CountConsecutive >= 3) Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I also tried a bunch of different solutions with formulas and conditional formatting as seen on SO and elsewhere, but it frankly seems clunky and not powerful enough

The actual files contain 16 columns @ 720 rows and I will have many of them to analyze.  My intent is to use filtering to look at just the highlighted cells.

Extra credit if the function can ignore a single '0' in a larger series of '1's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cycle through all columns: (Edit: Until it gets to the last column)

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim cl As Long, N As Long, i As Long, LastCL As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCL = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For cl = 2 To LastCL
    For i = 3 To N
        Set r1 = Cells(i, cl)
        Set r2 = r1.Offset(-1, 0)
        Set r3 = r1.Offset(-2, 0)
        If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = 1 And r3.Value = 1 Then
            Union(r1, r2, r3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

We will use a **sub** rather than a **function.**  This sub looks at column **B**

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim cl As String, N As Long, i As Long
    cl = "B"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To N
        Set r1 = Cells(i, cl)
        Set r2 = r1.Offset(-1, 0)
        Set r3 = r1.Offset(-2, 0)
        If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = 1 And r3.Value = 1 Then
            Union(r1, r2, r3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

you can adapt it for other columns.

**EDIT#1**

Here is the modification to call it with multiple columns (in this example **B** thru **G**)

```
Sub ColorCells(cl As Variant)
        Dim N As Long, i As Long
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To N
            Set r1 = Cells(i, cl)
            Set r2 = r1.Offset(-1, 0)
            Set r3 = r1.Offset(-2, 0)
            If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = 1 And r3.Value = 1 Then
                Union(r1, r2, r3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next i
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
    For i = 2 To 6
        Call ColorCells(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

In **VBA** functions (*UDF* s) are usually used to return values to cells and not for general cell updates.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as described for column b.  What's the best way to call a sub and can it be made generic?  I liked the idea of using a function because then I can just go to the bottom of a column, use my function (like a formula) and then copy it across to the other columns.  I have many files with variable column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional formatting as well.

If you data that you listed above is in the Range A2:E9 (need the buffer row at the top as you'll see in a bit), then you can select the Range B3:E9 and create a new rule, and `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and enter the following formula:

```
=OR(SUM(B1:B3)=3,SUM(B2:B4)=3,SUM(B3:B5)=3)
```

As for your extra credit, it's possible to do that, but you'll need to provide better criteria.